What is the grammatical relation between こそこそしたN and 汚れたN?
The two in the title, こそこそした, and 汚れた, are not necessarily related words, but are grammatically used in a similar way. For example, in both cases I technically can say:

こそこそしている男, Sneaky Boy


汚れている男, Dirty Boy

But this is not typically done, especially the second one. Instead, they are written this way, using the past tense:

こそこそした男, Sneaky Boy


汚れた男, Dirty Boy

Grammatically, we are just taking the resultative ている state and just flipping it to the past tense; effectively, 服は汚れた and 服は汚れている are the same, and the same can be said for こそこそ. However, does this grammar "rule" have a name, and am I even right to say that both of these words (the verb example and the onomatopoeia example) follow the same grammatical rule?

I'm not aware of the name for this "rule" but this has been discussed several times. What are the general principles of using verbs to modify nouns (e.g. 焦げるトースト/焦げたトースト)? / "太ってる猫" vs "太った猫" Do they answer your question?

Literally the first one in the answer. Sorry, I did not know the name of the concept to begin with.
